# Google Analytics shows 'null', Data-layer shows correct data

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to use the DOM Element variable in Google Tag Manager and i focussed on one element in my webpage. I have been following this video tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxEYZthbzp4

Everything seemed to work as i want. However when i looked in my Google analytics i see that the data-layer doesn't send the data that i want, but just 'null' (even though that in the google tag manager everything looks just fine).

How can i solve this problem?

[Screenshot of GTM datalayer & GA output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEq7L.png)
[image]

Comment: Can you please post screenshots of how you configured your variables and tags?

Comment: And don't look at the "summary" in preview mode, as "Analytics Mi" has pointed out in his answer DOM element variables will be available at DOM Ready or later - there is a good chance that your tag fires on pageview, before the HTML structure is avaible to extract data (so it might help if you change your trigger from pageview to domready).

Answer (score 1):

I think the value is populated after the data is sent to google analytics
check variable by individual events(pageview, dom ready, window loaded, gtm.click);
also please share your variable and trigger setup.

Hope this helps,
Cheers Analytics ML